# How much space is there on the battlefield?

Tags: hearthstone

The [legendary neutral minion card Onyxia](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Onyxia) has the following text:

> **Battlecry:** Summon 1/1 Welps until your side of the battlefield is full.

[image: Onyxia card]

So how much space is there on the battlefield? When will it be considered "full"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The maximum number of minions per side is 7.

source: http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Minion

Comment: Odd, there used to be a weird way to get an 8th minion on the board but I think that was an older version of the game.  It is worth restating that as of the current version, some effects such as Noble Sacrifice will not even trigger once you have 7 minions on the board!

Comment: All previous versions of the game were beta and don't really apply or have any significant relevance on the release version me thinks

Comment: @Ramhound Ah, sorry. The game felt so much more polished in late beta than most released games do these days -- I forgot the release was anything more than a regular ol' update.

Comment: Yes; it was but important difference. The beta was a testing ground for things that did and did not make it into the "final" version.